# Order By Date print Latest 20 records only in LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am Printing all latest records depending on when a book was published.(`PubEnd`). Now I am able to print all the books that are published in descending order.

**I need to print the 20 Latest published titles**. How can I do that??
Right now the code below is printing all books published in descending order.

```
var query = docs.Descendants(name)
        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Title = (string)x.Element(ns + "TITLE"),
                            Status = (string)x.Element(ns + "STATUS"),
                            PubEnd = (string)x.Element(ns + "PUB_END")

                        })                                              
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Title = x.Title,
            Status = x.Status,
            PubEnd = x.PubEnd,
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).ToList();

foreach (var book in query)
{
    if (book.Status == "Published")
    {
        Response.Write(book.Title);
        Response.Write(book.Status);
        Response.Write(book.PubEnd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Learn about Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D.

Comment: Formatting in VS does not work well for multiline object initializers (at least in VS 2008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `Take(20)`
2. Why are you building anonumous objects twice with the same values?

This should be what you need:

```
var list = docs.Descendants(name)
               .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Title = (string)x.Element(ns + "TITLE"),
                        Status = (string)x.Element(ns + "STATUS"),
                        PubEnd = (string)x.Element(ns + "PUB_END")
                    })
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).Take(20).ToList();
```

**If you want to get distinct result:**

```
var list = (...).OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).Distinct().Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: I just started learning Linq. I though I need to add it in the second select to be able to use book.title in Foreach loop. Thank you. I modified the code.

Comment: @SmilingLily. I added the distinct option to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
foreach (var book in query.Take(20))
{
   //print
}
```

If you *always* only need 20 update the query itself accordingly:

```
(..).OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you that is working. Do you know if I can add distinct here?

Comment: @SmilingLily. Use this: `(..).OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).Distinct().Take(20).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to use `Take(20)`

[Here is the documentation on Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Your code will become:

```
...OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).Take(20).ToList()
```

**UPDATE for DISTINCT**

[Here is the documentation for Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)

Your code would be this, I assume you want distinct before you take 20 :)

```
...OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).Distinct().Take(20).ToList()
```

Comment: Updated my response for your question on Distinct

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = docs.Descendants(name)
.Select(x => new
{
    Title = (string)x.Element(ns + "TITLE"),
    Status = (string)x.Element(ns + "STATUS"),
    PubEnd = (string)x.Element(ns + "PUB_END")

})
.OrderByDescending(x => x.PubEnd).Take(20); // Take will get the first N records.

foreach (var book in query)
{
    if (book.Status == "Published")
    {
        Response.Write(book.Title);
        Response.Write(book.Status);
        Response.Write(book.PubEnd);
    }
}
```